# Cassandra failed building secondary index upon restart

Tags: cassandra

Cassandra was killed possibly due to low memory on the server. Upon restart, Cassandra failed building an AsciiType secondary index with a java.lang.ClassCastException. Here is the cassandra log output:

```
INFO 16:31:37,109 Creating new index : ColumnDefinition {
     name=666f6c6c6f7754797065,
     validator=org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.AsciiType, 
     index_type=KEYS, 
     index_name='mySecondaryIndexField'
}

INFO 16:31:37,115 reading saved cache /var/lib/cassandra/saved_caches/MyProject-MyCF.mySecondaryIndexField-KeyCache

INFO 16:31:37,117 Opening /var/lib/cassandra/data/MyProject/MyCF/MyProject-MyCF.mySecondaryIndexField-hd-1 (399 bytes)

ERROR 16:31:37,121 Exception in thread Thread[SSTableBatchOpen:1,5,main]
**java.lang.ClassCastException: [B cannot be cast to java.nio.ByteBuffer**
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.AsciiType.compare(AsciiType.java:28)
        at org.apache.cassandra.dht.LocalToken.compareTo(LocalToken.java:45)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.DecoratedKey.compareTo(DecoratedKey.java:89)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.DecoratedKey.compareTo(DecoratedKey.java:38)
        at java.util.TreeMap.getEntry(TreeMap.java:345)
        at java.util.TreeMap.containsKey(TreeMap.java:226)
        at java.util.TreeSet.contains(TreeSet.java:234)
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTableReader.load(SSTableReader.java:396)
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTableReader.open(SSTableReader.java:187)
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTableReader$1.run(SSTableReader.java:225)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1146)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
```

Queries with this secondary index returned only a small portion of result set as a result. Cassnadra was then restarted again for a second time, this exception is not thrown and secondary index was rebuilt correctly and all queries have recovered and returned the results as expected.

There are only 2 possible String values for my secondary index field "mySecondaryIndexField".

Here is also the configuration for my Column Family:

```
Column Type - Standard
Comparator Type - org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.AsciiType
Read Repair Chance - 1
Index Options - name: mySecondaryIndexField
        validation_class: org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.AsciiType
        index_type: 0
        index_name: mySecondaryIndexField
        index_options: 
Gc Grace Seconds - 864000
Default Validation Class - org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.BytesType
Id - 1023
Min Compaction Threshold - 4
Max Compaction Threshold - 32
Replicate On Write - 1
Key Validation Class - org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.BytesType
Compaction Strategy - org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy
Compaction Strategy Options - None
Sstable Compression -org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.SnappyCompressor
Caching - KEYS_ONLY
```

Does anyone have run into similar problems? Cassandra version is 1.1.1.

Comment: I'd strongly recommend an upgrade - many bugs have been fixed since 1.1.12 is the latest 1.1 release.

Comment: Thanks Richard. That's what I ended up doing but was wondering if anyone has seen similar issues and found out what's causing it. As this problem doesn't appear all the time even with 1.1.1 so I cannot be sure if 1.1.12 actually fixed the problem...